# Android downloaded file's size on card is bigger than the download size

Tags: android

i have a weird thing when downloading file from an URL in my program.
I perform check of available updates of files on server by checking same file's size on the device and on the server. When i use getContentLength method of URLConnection class i get one size, then i download and check the downloaded size by bytes which get downloaded and get same size. But when i look at the size of the files on the SDCard they are about 1.4 times bigger. Why does this happen? 
So, basically i download one size and get different on SDCard and thats why i can't check if they are updated by asking the server.
URL is of https type, files are .ics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was with the encoding. I had to use OutputStreamWriter with secon parameter "UTF8". And that aswell solved the problem with cyrylic letters in the text.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's due to filesystem overhead.  I assume you're writing to a FAT32 SD card, in which case there may be significant overhead in some cases.

According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table):

> "Note however, that files are allocated in units of clusters, so if a 1 kB file resides in a 32 kB cluster, 31 kB are wasted."

Consider trying with large files or files of different sizes if possible, and see if the ratio of expected to actual size remains the same.

Comment: i download 5 files of different sizes and each one has (on card space)/(downloaded size) value different but it never gets less than 1.1 and more than 2. But i guess your idea about filesystem overhead might be just right, because these files are 110 KB max. thanks.